# Draw a rectangle on an image with Python PIL with coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

If you look in MS Paint, and when you look in the bottom left corner, you see that it gives coordinates where the page on the top left is "**1**, 1px". I do not care about the pixels, but I do care about the **1**. I have the following example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = np.array(Image.open('image.JPG'), dtype=np.uint8)

# Create figure and axes
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Display the image
ax.imshow(im)

# Create a Rectangle patch
rect = patches.Rectangle((988,988),988,30,linewidth=1,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')

# Add the patch to the Axes
ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
```

However, I would like the rectangle that is drawn to be based on the cöordinates which Paint gives. How can I incorporate it into this code so that it recognizes it?

Comment: What do you mean by *coordinates paint gives*?

Comment: The coordinates used in PIL and MS Paint are the same. Can you be more elaborate?

Comment: Ah you are right! It works, thanks!!